# What mapping application also leaves digital Breadcrumbs?

Tags: ios, gps

I've moved into a new area of the city and it would be nice to feel like I've explored the area properly. I'd like to be able to say that I've walked down every street within, say a mile.  I'm looking for an app that might help me track any I've missed.

Esentially I want an app that overlays a gps breadcrumb over where I've been walking. Googling for this hasn't got me very far because there is a app called 'breadcrumb' that let's uses mark about eight locations they want to come back to.  I'd just like to start the app, leave the house for a bit, and then see where I've got to.  Any ideas for what would be a useful app for me?